# Prevent c# exe from exe extractor

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, security, exe

How can I prevent my C# exe from exe extractor like
http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx and
https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET

Comment: simple answer is that you can't, for a computer to run an exe it has to be able to read it, if a computer can read its instructions from the file then another program can read it and display those instructions to a human, the best you can do is as @SebastianSchulz says make it harder for humans to make sense out of that output

Answer (score 0):

You Cant prevent it if you think practically but you can do it in such way that even after extract its don't get in much use or not easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to make your code impossible to decompile.

Additionally, there's no such thing as "encrypting" a .NET assembly (or any binary) while still maintaining its ability to be executable.

What you're looking for is an obfuscator - a tool that mangles the code enough to make it harder for a human reader to understand. There is one called Dotfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like this http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/ Which is an Obfuscator designed to make your code Difficult (but not impossible) to Reverse Engineer and Decompile, Please do note however, that it is impossible to prevent Decompilation but it is possible to make the person's life harder trying to decompile it.